# Distance an object has fallen given time

Tags: gravity, kinematics, free-fall

I am in Honors Physics, and need help understanding this:

The acceleration of Earth's gravity is 9.8 $m/s^2$, so when an object starts from rest, **9.8** $= x/t^2$, where $x$ is distance the object will fallen and $t$ is the time it will take to fall that distance, right?

When I plug $v_i= 0$ and $a=9.8$ in to the equation $x=v_it+\frac{at^2}{2}$, however, the result is $x=\frac{9.8t^2}{2}$ or **4.9** $= x/t^2$. Why is this? What is going on here?

Comment: *The acceleration of Earth's gravity is 9.8 m/$s^2$, so when an object starts from rest, 9.8 =x/$t^2$=x/$t^2$, where xx is distance the object will fallen and tt is the time it will take to fall that distance, right?* **--No.**

Comment: Your definition of acceleration in the second paragraph is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Average acceleration is defined as $a = \Delta v/\Delta t$ where $\Delta v$ is the change in velocity and $\Delta t$ is the change in time. You are using the change in distance to determine the acceleration due to gravity. Dimensional analysis can work to give an approximation, but it doesn't necessarily give you the correct answer. You can see here that using dimensional analysis has you off by a factor of 2.

Comment: Please explain dimensional analysis.

Comment: The dimensions of acceleration are length/time^2 which is what I feel you used to come up with your idea of the acceleration being x/t^2. However, acceleration is actually defined as the change of velocity over time. It's not valid to say that acceleration is distance traveled over time squared. The units work out, but the conclusion is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}v=u+at\\ \Rightarrow v=gt\\ \Rightarrow g=\dfrac{v}{t} \cdots (1)\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}s=ut+\dfrac{1}{2}at^{2}\\ \Rightarrow s=\dfrac{1}{2}gt^{2}\\ \Rightarrow g=\dfrac{2s}{t^{2}}\cdots (2)\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}s=vt-\dfrac{1}{2}at^{2}\\ \Rightarrow s-vt=-\dfrac{1}{2}at^{2}\\ \Rightarrow g=\dfrac{2\left( vt-s\right) }{t^{2}} \cdots (3)\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}v^{2}-u^{2}=2as\\ \Rightarrow v^{2}=2as\\ \Rightarrow g=\dfrac{v^{2}}{2s} \cdots (4)\end{aligned}
$$

$$g=\dfrac{v}{t}=\dfrac{2s}{t^{2}}=\dfrac{2\left( vt-s\right) }{t^{2}}=\dfrac{v^{2}}{2s}=9.8\ \mathrm{m s^{-2}}$$